# How to generate an XML file for face detection

Tags: c++, opencv

Now I am creating my own classifier for face detection.now I want to train the classifier.So when I give the command 'opencv_haartraining -data facehaar -vec vecfile.vec  -bg negatives.txt -npos 3 -nneg 5 -nstages 30 -w 30 -h 32' it shows like this.What is this error?I don't understand?Could any one help me?

```
Data dir name: facehaar
Vec file name: vecfile.vec
BG  file name: negatives.txt, is a vecfile: no
Num pos: 3
Num neg: 5
Num stages: 30
Num splits: 1 (stump as weak classifier)
Mem: 200 MB
Symmetric: TRUE
Min hit rate: 0.995000
Max false alarm rate: 0.500000
Weight trimming: 0.950000
Equal weights: FALSE
Mode: BASIC
Width: 30
Height: 32
Applied boosting algorithm: GAB
Error (valid only for Discrete and Real AdaBoost): misclass
Max number of splits in tree cascade: 0
Min number of positive samples per cluster: 500
Required leaf false alarm rate: 9.31323e-10

Tree Classifier
 Stage
  +---+
  |  0|
  +---+


Number of features used : 234720

Parent node: NULL

*** 1 cluster ***
 POS: 3 3 1.000000
 Invalid background description file.
```

Comment: Which is the content of "negatives.txt"? It should contain absolute paths of image files

Comment: thanks I got this..But now I want to generate an XML file.So for that I use convert_cascade command.But it shows no such command.why?

Comment: Have you looked in the OpenCV samples directory? convert_cascade should be there: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/c/convert_cascade.c